# How to make a family of related optional-arg macros reliable

Tags: macros, errors

I have some working, but unreliable `\def` magic I use to reduce boilerplate regarding mathematical indices.  (This is in LaTeX, but I couldn't think of a way to do it using `newcommand`).

```
\makeatletter
\def\@subarg[#1]{_{\rm #1}}

\def\Lam{{\Lambda}\@ifnextchar[\@subarg{}}
\def\Reg{{\cal R}\@ifnextchar[\@subarg{}}
% .
% .
% many similar definitions
% .
% .

\makeatother
```

The idea is that when I say`\Lam[frog]`, the `\@subarg@` macro gobbles up optional arg and puts it in roman.  If I don't want a roman subscript, I can still do `\Lam` and `\Lam_k` as usual.

All this works, but dodgily. I'm sorry I can't characterise the errors very well, but I know there is trouble in section headings.

```
\subsubsection{Start $\Lam[fee] fi$ fo }
\subsubsection{Start $\Lam[fee] fi$ }
\subsubsection{Start $\Lam[fee]$ }
```

All generate `! Missing \endcsname inserted.`

While  both of

```
\subsubsection{Start $\Lam$ }
\subsubsection{Start $\Lam$}
```

Generate: `! Argument of \@sect has an extra }.`

Does anyone have  a clue how to make the macros more robust?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you're facing creeps in because you're inserting content into a fragile macro (a sectional unit). This sectional unit sends stuff to be set where called, but also the ToC, and that's where you run into problems.

One way around it is to actually `\protect` your macros when using them in a sectional unit (as in, `\protect\Lam...`). Alternatively, you ask "how can you make them more robust?" Well, use `\DeclareRobustCommand`!

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\@subarg[#1]{_{\mathrm{#1}}}

\DeclareRobustCommand\Lam{\Lambda\@ifnextchar[\@subarg{}}
\DeclareRobustCommand\Reg{\mathcal{R}\@ifnextchar[\@subarg{}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\section{Start $\Lam[fee] fi$ fo}
\section{Start $\Lam[fee] fi$}
\section{Start $\Lam[fee]$}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ha! `DeclareRobustCommand`, ha!  Now all we need is the `makeitwork` shell command and computing will be easy.

Answer (score 3):

You should avoid `\@ifnextchar` when higher level tools are available; for your case I'd use `\newcommand`:

```
\newcommand{\Lam}[1][]{%
  \Lambda
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax % test if the optional argument is empty
    % do nothing
  \else
    _\textnormal{#1}
  \fi
}
```

This will not incur in the fragility problem you're experimenting, because commands having optional arguments defined with `\newcommand` are robust.

Of course, typing several instances of similar code is annoying and even wrong. So we can define a catch all macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\definevariable}[2]{% #1 = macro, #2 = actual variable
  \newcommand{#1}{#2\definevariabletestargument}%
}
\newcommand\definevariabletestargument[1][]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax % test if the optional argument is empty
    % do nothing
  \else
    _\textnormal{#1}%
  \fi
}

\definevariable{\Lam}{\Lambda}
\definevariable{\Reg}{\mathcal{R}}

\begin{document}

\section{Here we have $\Reg$}

\subsection{With subscript $\Reg[xy]$}

\subsection{And $\Lam$}

\subsection{With subscript $\Lam[fee]$}

\end{document}
```

Note the use of `\textnormal` rather than `\mathrm`, which allows for spaces in the input, for instance.

An even more powerful tool is `xparse`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\definevariable}{mm}{% #1 = macro, #2 = actual variable
  \NewDocumentCommand{#1}{o}{%
    #2%
    \IfValueT{##1}{_\textnormal{##1}}%
  }%
}

\definevariable{\Lam}{\Lambda}
\definevariable{\Reg}{\mathcal{R}}

\begin{document}

\section{Here we have $\Reg$}

\subsection{With subscript $\Reg[xy]$}

\subsection{And $\Lam$}

\subsection{With subscript $\Lam[fee]$}

\end{document}
```

[image]